# In ASP.NET which data-type we can't store in session?

Tags: c#, asp.net

data-type that is not allowed to store in asp.net session or is there any data-type which raises an error while storing in session.

```
 data-type st=some data;
 session["x"]=st;
```

Comment: You can store like everything

Comment: Well, not really everything (as there are some non-serializable types). It depends on the serialization used. But it's a bit hard to track down the technical docs sometimes, especially since such has changed over the years (Binary/ISerializable, XML, DCS..)

Comment: You can store a lot of thing in Session but not recommended cause it will burden the server if you store big stuff

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the session-state mode. With InProc you can store everything, otherwise (e.g. Session State Server or SQL Server) only primitives and serializable objects.

See [MSDN: Session-State Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) for more information.

Comment: can we store session in session

Comment: like sessios["dd"]=sessions["xyz"];

Comment: Yes... You 'store' the value in a new session. But why should you?

Comment: @MeerDeen That is not storing 'session in session'; it is simply assigning an already stored object under a different name (leaving the original in place).